# Two long running tasks with one update thread using GCD

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to update a grouped tableview.  There is a filter so sometimes the data is not shown in the second section.  Data is always shown in the first section.  Because the query takes awhile, I'm trying to put things in the background and then update the UI on the main thread.  I can't seem to get it to work however and was wondering what I'm doing wrong.  Basically the first section will show the data properly, but the second section will not show its data at all.  Here's some pseudo code to illustrate what I'm currently trying

```
dispatch_queue_t lowQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

dispatch_async(lowQueue, ^{
    // long running task for section 1

    if (filter == SHOW_SECTION_2) {
         // long running task for section 2

          dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
          // update main thread UI for long running task 2
          [self.tableView reloadData]; 
          });
    }

    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
         // update main thread UI for long running task 1
          [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```

If I do it for just one table section, it works. It's the fact I need to update 2 things that I cannot find the right way to do it.  Thanks.

Edit: I'm just trying to update a table view.  So after I get my data, I just call reload data.

Comment: what type of views or data are you trying to update, please post more code

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith added more code.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but the way your code is structured (with the `if` statement nested inside the first `dispatch_async` block) means the 2nd task won't even get dispatched until the 1st task is totally finished. Is that the way you intended? At the very least, you'd want to move the `if` statement to a location after the `dispatch_async` at the bottom of your code, so the UI updates after the 1st task is done regardless of the state of the 2nd task.

Comment: @smileyborg Ya I wasn't really sure what the best way is to get the data in the background for multiple tasks, and update in one spot with a conditional.  What I ended up doing was getting the data for both tasks, and then in the updating of the mainQueue, I only update where needed.  It works for now, but I'd prefer the right way to do it.